# Measuring distance between two vertices on linear shapefile using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, point, distance, intersection

In QGIS 3.22.5 I would need to measure the distance in meters between two vertices on a linear shapefile. This linear shapefile is a transect that has a vertex on the shoreline.

How do I measure the distance between this latter vertex and another point along the transect in which the transect intersects a polygonal shapefile?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the point on the shore is the start-point of the line. To create the line from here until the crosspoint with the green polygon and measure the length of this line, use this expression:

```
length(
    make_line (
        start_point($geometry),
        intersection (
            $geometry, 
            boundary(
                overlay_intersects('green', $geometry)[0]
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Replace `green` in line 7 by the name of your polygon layer. If the point on the shore is the end-point of the line, replace `start_point` in line 3 of the expression by `end_point`.

*Red line, created based on the expression above, is that part of the black line from the start point until the crossing point with the polygon's boundary:*

[image]